# How to separate HTML by p/div/h1-6 tag which contains at least 10 words

Tags: php, html

I need to separate string with html by p/div/h1-6 tags, but just in case, that the tag itslef contains at least 10/20/30 words.

Examples:

1)

```
$string = '<div class="main"><span>a b c d</span><div><div><div><h3>a b c d e f g h i j</h3><div><p>In this paragraph <b>is not more than</b> ten words.</p></div></div></div></div></div>';

$output[0] = '<div class="main"><span>a b c d</span><div><div><div><h3>a b c d e f g h i j</h3>'; // only in tag h3 is at least 10 words
$output[1] = '<div><p>In this paragraph <b>is not more than</b> ten words.</p></div></div></div></div></div>'; // here is not more than 10 words in tag p, it is just rest of string
```

2)

```
$string = '<div class="main"><span>a b c d e f g h i j</span><div><div><div><h3>a b c d e f g h i j</h3><div><p>In this paragraph <b>is more than</b> ten words just now, right?.</p></div></div></div></div></div>';

$output[0] = '<div class="main"><span>a b c d e f g h i j</span>';
$output[1] = '<div><div><div><h3>a b c d e f g h i j</h3>';
$output[2] = '<div><p>In this paragraph <b>is more than</b> ten words just now, right?.</p></div></div></div></div></div>';
```

3)

```
$string = '<div class="main"><span>a b c d e f g h i j</span><div><div><div><h3>a b c d e f g h i j</h3><div><p>In this paragraph <b>is more than</b> ten words <p>Another paragraph with more than 10 words words words words words words</p> just now, right?.</p></div></div></div></div></div>';


$output[0] = '<div class="main"><span>a b c d e f g h i j</span>';
$output[1] = '<div><div><div><h3>a b c d e f g h i j</h3>';
$output[2] = 'In this paragraph <b>is more than</b> ten words <p>Another paragraph with more than 10 words words words words words words</p>';
$output[3] = ' just now, right?.</p></div></div></div></div></div>';
```

I simply need to segment long string with html to smaller parts, but this smaller parts must make sense (because of context). (Words are too small parts, sentences are not reliable (separate by dot, comma, dash etc. is not realiable - for example, dot does not mean end of sentence, right?))

Comment: I have to ask: What do you plan on doing with the partial/fragmented tags? In your example you're splitting up parent `<div>` elements making them invalid (one output has `<div><div><div>` and the other `</div></div></div>`)

Comment: Separated parts are shown to user (escaped), so invalid html output is not problem in this case. After this, parts are joined back together, so html will be OK in final result.